# python paramiko ssh session does not get the system path

Tags: python, path, system, paramiko

I'm facing a problem that as I ssh to another machine, my paramiko ssh session does not see the same system PATH as when I manually ssh to the machine.
Here is my python code:

```
cmd = "echo $PATH"
try:
    ssh.connect(ip, username=username, password=password)
except Exception as ex:
    raise Exception("Failed to connect to %s with credentials username='%s' password='%s' %s" \
          % (ip, username, password, ex.message) )

ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
output = ssh_stdout.read()
```

The output show /usr/bin:/bin
but when I manually ssh to the machine, there are several other paths on the system PATH.
Please help.

Answer (score 17):

I don't think any bashrc or profile scripts are being sourced when you use exec_command(). Maybe try the following:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("bash -lc 'echo $PATH'")
my_path = stdout.read().rstrip()
```

If the problem is that you are trying to run a command that's normally in your PATH, but isn't when you use exec_command(), you're probably better off calling the command by its absolute path (run "which [command]" when you're logged into the other machine normally to find out what that is).

Answer (score 8):

You better to load the bash_profile before you run your command. Otherwise you may get a 'command not found' exception.

For example，I write the command `command = 'mysqldump -uu -pp -h1.1.1.1 -P999 table > table.sql'` in the purpose of dumping a Mysql table

Then I have to load the bash_profile manually before that dumping command by typing `. ~/.profile; .~/.bash_profile;`.

## Example

```
my_command  = 'mysqldump -uu -pp -h1.1.1.1 -P999 table > table.sql;'

pre_command = """
. ~/.profile;
. ~/.bash_profile;
"""

command = pre_command + my_command

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
```

Comment: It should fail if user has no .profile or .bash_profile